# Jquery slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery slideUp and slideDown on this site of mine.

http://ourrecipes.mdssoftware.com.au/

In IE this works fine. But in Chrome when the slideDown completes the page jitters for a second, as you will see.

There is alot code so I dont want to post it.

But this is the javascript that does slide calls.

Malcolm

```
selectedRecipe = function (anchor) {

    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var rid = href.split("-")[1];

    $("#RecipeID").val(rid);

    var url = "/Recipes/GetRecipeView";

    $('#divrecipe').slideUp('slow');
     $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data: { rid: rid },
        beforeSend: function () { $.blockUI({ message: '<h2><img src="../Content/Images/FhHRx.gif" style="margin-top:20px;margin-right:20px"/> Loading...</h2>' }) },
        complete: function() { $.unblockUI() },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divrecipe").html(data);
            $('#divrecipe').slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Looks like your Postitnote.png file is quite big. Maybe try to reduce the images size ? Or preload ? I know it's complicated but would it be possible to reproduce in a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the problem, if I type this into the js console, I duplicate the problem:

```
$("#divrecipe").slideUp("slow");$("#divrecipe").slideDown("slow")
```

If I comment out the following css for #divrecipe:

```
/* height: 96%; */
```

then rerunning my test code doesn't exhibit the same effect.